# find first number in a string followed by x amount of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

```
string sChar = "_$$$ASDF 123-456-789123123XXX";
string sChar = "$$VIC123-456-789pppEEX";
```

I would like to parse the above examples of sChar to result in the following value

`123-456-789`

What this regex would do is find the first Number in the string as well as the next 10 characters.  The next 10 characters can be special characters, alpha, or numberic.

Comment: Can you post your current regex?

Comment: Im new to this and do not have any regex done at all.

Comment: Maybe firstly trim first 10 characters, then find numbers?

Comment: I was previously using sChar.substring(0, 11);

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript.  What language are you using?

Comment: the issue is that the characters leading up to the first number are an unknown amount.  I only care about the first number, and the next 10 characters.

Comment: sorry... it is javascript.  I just typed it out like that.  its not a copy/paste of my code.

Comment: You can try something along the lines of `str.match(/[0-9].{1,10}/)`, but what you need to do is google simple JS regex tutorials. (P.S. In JavaScript the `string` type declaration doesn't exist, you simply use `var`)

Comment: You can check here http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to get started with regex. -- _"Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"_. -- Check here also on how to ask good questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Comment: @nbrooks that is followed by `1 to 10 characters` resulting in `up to 11 characters`; if you wanted just 11 characters you would do `/\d.{10}/`

Comment: Yes... I understand that I should learn it.  Its just that customer changed my input and now I have to get solution quickly.  last minute thing.

Comment: Paul S.  That seems to work perfectly.  Let me do some testing on this to make sure its good to go.

Comment: Downvoting for lack of research. Since you know regular expressions are an appropriate solution, then do some research on how to using them instead of asking SO to write code for you. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great resource for this.

Comment: var oRegEx = new RegExp('\\d.{10}', 'g');
sChar = oRegEx.exec(sChar);

Comment: @dancrumb sorry dude... regex is hieroglyphics to me.  I needed a quick solution.  thanks for your understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution for you:

```
var sChar = "_$$$ASDF 123-456-789123123XXX";
//string sChar = "$$VIC123-456-789pppEEX";

var indexDigit = sChar.search(/[\d]/);
var str = sChar.substring(indexDigit, indexDigit+11);
alert(str);
```

I see an answer like this:

```
var str = sChar.match(/\d.{10}/);
alert(str)
```

That won't work:

Try the following:

```
var sChar = "_$$$ASDF 123-4$6-7";
var sChar2 = "$$VIC987-6$4-3";

var indexDigit = sChar.search(/[\d]/);
var str = sChar.substring(indexDigit, indexDigit+11);
alert(str);//returns "123-4$6-7"

var str2 = sChar2.match(/\d.{10}/);
alert(str2);//returns null
```